# What does "probate by truck" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is also explained here but I don't quite understand the role of "by truck" in this phrase. Can somebody help me, please?

"Finally, if the Bitcoins are not listed in a will, they are susceptible to what estate lawyers call “**probate by truck**”—where heirs walk off with property by claiming that “he would have wanted me to have it.” The difference is, instead of a favorite lamp or piece of jewelry, a relative might walk off with the private key to a Bitcoin wallet worth thousands or millions of dollars."

Source: http://fortune.com/2017/09/26/cryptocurrency-bitcoin-death/

Comment: Interesting. A quick Google shows that this phrase has virtually never before been used on the internet, although the few documents in which it is, assume enough familiarity with the phrase that it doesn't need to be explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phrase follows the pattern {action} by {method}.

> Execution by electrocution.
>
> Death by gunshot.

That pattern is often used in witticisms which play on the pattern:

> Death by chocolate.

There, the chocolate is understood to be so rich, so high in fat-content and calories, that it is for all intents and purposes a lethal weapon.

In the phrase

> Probate by truck

"by truck" is metonymy. The phrase refers to the vehicle heirs use to haul away goods not specifically designated in a will, such as pieces of furniture; the vehicle often used in  such an act stands for the abstract act itself, the informal (and illicit) appropriation of items by heirs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the words have their normal meanings:

**by** = *by means of*, or *using*.

**truck** = a large, heavy motor vehicle designed for transporting goods or materials.

So "by truck" = "by means of using a large motor vehicle designed for transporting goods".

So the words are interpreted literally, but the meaning of the whole phrase is jocular:

**Regular, normal probate:**  "Let's all go to court to discuss Uncle Henry's will and who will inherit his belongings."

**Probate by truck:**  "I'm going to go to Uncle Henry's house with a truck and take whatever I want before his other heirs have a chance to get anything."